# Apache producing 301 for apparently valid URL (Pen test)

Tags: apache-2.4

I'm using Burp Suite pen-tester on a site and it is showing up a minor issues that I can probably ignore, but I would like to get to the bottom of what is going on anyway.

A GET request is being made as follows:

```
GET /faqs/?x9rf3mkslk=1 HTTP/1.1
Host: abc.com
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7
Accept-Language: en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.6167.85 Safari/537.36
Connection: close
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Sec-CH-UA: ".Not/A)Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="121", "Chromium";v="121"
Sec-CH-UA-Platform: Windows
Sec-CH-UA-Mobile: ?0
Content-Length: 0
```

And the response is a 301 redirect:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Mon, 12 Feb 2024 10:01:53 GMT
Server: Apache
Location: https://abc.comfaqs/?x9rf3mkslk=1
Content-Length: 249
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>301 Moved Permanently</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Moved Permanently</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="https://abc.comfaqs/?x9rf3mkslk=1">here</a>.</p>
</body></html>
```

For this domain there are no 301 redirects setup in the Apache config or in .htaccess. But the confusing thing is how Apache is processing this request. The request has the location `abc.com` and the GET is `/faqs/?x9rf3mkslk=1` but if I put `abc.com/faqs/?x9rf3mkslk=1` into my browser the page loads normally as is logged properly. The request from Burp however are being logged in the default HTTPD logs folder rather than the location of the domains logs. So it is being logged as if the request is being made to the IP as oppose to the domain, or the server host domain (which is different).

Additionally you will notice in the 301 response there is no forward slash after the domain so the the link in the HTML is invalid.

I'd like to know how this 301 is being produced?

Comment: A (broken) redirect can be created in roughly three places with an apache web server: in the main apache httpd config (or any of the configuration snippets  pulled into that main config with `Include` and similar directives) ; by directory overrides (a `.htaccess` in any directory  allowed by an `AllowOverride` leading up to the the requested resource) or by the application code. - Note that your browser will cache 301 redirects, honor HSTS, the HSTS pre-load list and will rewrite `http://example.dev/something` to `https://example.dev/something` before even attempting to make that request

Comment: Unless of course your testing with `abc.com`, in your questions please refrain from using random domain names and use either your *own domain* or one of the [RFC 6761](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6761#section-6.5) reserved domain names such as  `example.com`, `example.org`  or similar . Please refer to [this Q&A](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/963/37681) for our recommendations with regards to how and what (not) to obfuscate in your questions.

Comment: No I am using my own domain name, there are no redirects for this request in any of those locations so I am confused as to how it is occurring. I don't think caching is an issue as this page has been the same for a long time.